# Specify innertheme for an rmarkdown beamer presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown

The default bullets in the AnnArbor theme are ugly bullet points I want to switch for the cleaner arrow type bullet points in the default theme.  Do you know how I can specify the innertheme for rmarkdown's beamer presentation in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Markdown often includes easy to access options to be used in the yaml front matter. However, in the event that such an option has not been made available, we can always resort to `header-includes` to include arbitrary LaTeX code in the preamble.

Here's how you could use that to change the `innertheme`:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
    - \useinnertheme{rectangles}
---
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the size of bullets? I've tried including `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]{3pt}` in the header, as specified [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (pg 176) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480038/changing-the-bullet-list-symbol-in-beamer-when-used-from-pandoc), but it fails to compile: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. Error: LaTeX failed to compile untitled.tex.`

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to bullet point size and style:

```
--------
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
   - \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize$\bowtie$}
   - \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\scriptsize$\diamond$}
   - \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\scriptsize$\gg$}
--------
```

You can swap out "\bowtie" for any Latex symbol (with escape slash) or raw text (without escape slash). "\default" will give you the default symbols.

This will work to change bullet point symbols in default theme Beamer, and will also override a generally applied theme (like AnnArbor).